how to override user's locale for number format in Apex data upsert operation
I've a Database.upsert operation on Apex base. But a user's locale(who runs the upsert operation) is Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan). Because of the number format that user has the numbers being upserted without decimal point. Is there a way to bypass user's number format on Apex level?

How are these values being obtained? Is it through an API or a UI? Either way, IMO, you must make sure to use standard ISO value formatting. The latter is handled in conversions Salesforce does based on actual user locales, but if you don't have a specific user logging in for the operation then you will need to do the conversions yourself. Again in my opinion.

Users are uploading an excel file with the related data column by column. Then these are being mapped to the custom object's fields. For example, the value is 161.30 but is upserted as 16130. I'll check out the locale thing in Salesforce documentation, thank you @PhilW
